# Need to send Email attachment with ASP Vbscript code

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I am trying to send attachemnet with the below code in a classic ASP application.This application fetches mail to , mail from address etc from DB. Now the catch is from the frond end when the user browses a document then without storing the documnet anywhere(i.e in database or server), I need to attach the document as an attachemnt with the below mail piece code..Pls suggest..

```
sql = "insert INTO RSP_SSR_ENTRY(SR_ID_NBR, SA_ID_NBR, IMO_NBR ,INSPECTION_SEQ_NBR, INSPECTION_DTM, PO_ID_NBR, OPERATIONAL_STATUS_TXT, REPORT_Q2_IND, REPORT_Q3_IND, REPORT_Q4_IND, REPORT_Q5_IND, REPORT_Q6_IND,   REPORT_Q7_IND, REPORT_Q8_IND, REPORT_Q9_IND, REPORT_Q10_IND, REPORT_Q11_IND, REPORT_Q12_IND, REPORT_Q13_IND, REPORT_QA_IND, REPORT_QB_IND, SUBMITTED_DTM) VALUES(0, " & said & ", " & ssr_imo & ", " & ssr_ins_nr & ", " & ssr_ins_date & ", " & ssr_port_id & ", '" & opStat & "', '" & ssr_q2 & "', '" & ssr_q3 & "', '" & ssr_q4 & "', '" & ssr_q5 & "', '" & ssr_q6 & "', '" & ssr_q7 & "', '" & ssr_q8 & "', '" & ssr_q9 & "', '" & ssr_q10 & "', '" & ssr_q11 & "', '" & ssr_q12 & "', '" & ssr_q13 & "','" & ssr_qa & "', '" & ssr_qb & "', "&right_now&")"

        debugNote sql
        session("sqlInsertText") = sql
        Set db1 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
        db1.Open GV_VIEW_DB_String 

        Set rsInsert = db1.Execute(sql)

            session("duplicateInsert_ssr") = false
            set rsInsert = nothing
            Set dbl = nothing 

        'lookup the name of the Ship
        shipName = ssr_ship_name & " ("&ssr_imo&")"

        'send an email for SSR
        mailbody = GV_EMAIL_TOP 
        'mailbody = mailbody & "For processing on " & FormatDateTime(dateadd("d", 1, now()), 1) & "<br />"
        mailbody = mailbody & "Date time of SSR Upload : " & Day(date()) & " " & MonthName(Month(date()), true) & " " & Year(date()) & " " & Hour(time()) & ":" & Minute(time()) &  "<br />"
        mailbody = mailbody & "Name and IMO number of Ship : " & shipName & "<br />"
        mailbody = mailbody & "Inspection number : " & ssr_ins_nr & "<br />"
        mailbody = mailbody & "Submitted by : " & subName  & " (" & subEmail & ")<br />"

        'mailsubject = "S.H.I.P - SSR report has been submitted "
        mailsubject = "SSR report for " & shipName &  "has been submitted "

        ShipEmail mailbody, "SHIP Admin user", GV_SSR_MAIL_TO, "", "", mailsubject
```

Comment: Is this asp.net, asp classic or vbscript? Please update tags accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send a File it must always be stored (temporarily) on the server that sends the mails!

Not knowing what your ShipEmail function looks like and assuming you're using CDO.Message it would be something like this:

```
Set cdoMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message") 
cdoMessage.Subject = "Some Message" 
cdoMessage.From = "testfrom@test.com" 
cdoMessage.To = "testto@test.com" 
'cdoMessage.TextBody = "This is some sample message text." 
cdoMessage.HTMLBody = "This is some sample html message text." 
'File on Server!
cdoMessage.AddAttachment "c:\emailpickup\test.txt"
cdoMessage.Send
```

If you want to embedd images look into `AddRelatedBodyPart`